# Given a complex JAXB graph, what is best way to grab an item out of it?

Tags: java, jaxb

Assuming you know where in the graph it is, how do you grab an item out of the graph without using JXPath, which according to the docs simply iterates until it finds the next node and then iterates again for the next and so on... Yup. Nested loops. Exactly what they told us to avoid like the plague in College. The other thing I want to avoid is this:

```
thingOne.getValue()
    .getWidget().getValue()
    .getAnotherWidget().getValue()
    .getAdNauseum()
```

So if I wanted to mock this for a test I would need a new mock at every level that just returns the next mock. The horror.... ;-)

At this point I'll take any optimization I can get. Even if it's just some way to dodge `getValue()`.

Comment: Why not just use samples data instead of mocking?

Comment: You didn't listen attentively enough in College :-) For k levels of nested loops of (average) length n you have indeed the horrible O(n^k). But, to locate elements on k levels levels of (average) length n you just need O(k*n/2). You don't need to examine all possible XPaths of length k for locating a single XPath target at level k...

Comment: Color me unimpressed since I could probably write something better. Maybe I will but right now I need to focus on getting a new contract. I'm aboard a sinking ship.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your objects to org.w3c.dom.Document with :

```
JAXBContext contextJaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(xml.getClass());
Marshaller marshaller = contextJaxb.createMarshaller();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
marshaller.marshal(xml, doc);
```

And then search for one object in it with :

```
private Element getFirstElementsByTagName(final String name, final Namespace nameSpace, final Element root) {
    List<Element> list = new ArrayList<Element>(root.getChildren(name, nameSpace));
    Iterator<Element> iterator = root.getChildren().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext() && list.isEmpty()) {
        Element next = iterator.next();
        Element element = this.getFirstElementsByTagName(name, nameSpace, next);
        if(element != null) {
            list.add(element);
        }
    }
    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This seems very similar to the JXPath answer as it seems like you would have to use it at each level, resulting in nested loops. If not, then it seems like you would have a problem with objects having the same name but different locations. I might be wrong though.

Comment: If you know exactly how to walk the tree to obtain that element, then why don't you directly walk the tree to obtain the element ? If you only know it at runtime then you can use XPath : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Comment: I think that in the end I may be struggling to solve a problem that is best solved architecturally. IMHO, if this is just internal data, then JSON should have been used rather than XML. In answer to your question, that nesting of calls combined with getValue which returns a generic, causes problems with mocking. You'd need a new mock for each level.

Comment: I suppose you mean "JAXB object graph", which is a hierarchy of POJOs. If you have this you can indeed use a sequence of getters. If you want to mock this, you just need to know the class of the result - what would be the purpose of mocking all the levels from the root down?